# Azure Media Player Doesn't Support Browser

Tags: azure, media-player, azure-media-services

I have created a Azure Media Service WhichEncode, Encrpts and creates the delivery policy for asset. I am generating the URL which is perfect but doesnt play with Azure Media Player. I get error, can anyone help on this.
[image: This is the error I get When try to play my encrypted Video]

**Edit:** I tried uploading and manually apply content protection and then playing media from azure itself. which also returns the similar error.
[image]

Comment: can you post a URL that reproduces the issue?
What browser is this occurring on? Also what type of encryption are you using?

Comment: I am using AES-128 Encryption as provided by Azure Media Service. I can't share you the Url, as i am not allowed but am sure you can recreate the scenario. Let me know if i have to add the steps.

Comment: do you get the same error with this video: http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html?url=%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F830584f8-f0c8-4e41-968b-6538b9380aa5%2FTearsOfSteelTeaser.ism%2Fmanifest&aes=true&aestoken=Bearer%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OmF6dXJlOm1lZGlhc2VydmljZXM6Y29udGVudGtleWlkZW50aWZpZXIiOiI5ZGRhMGJjYy01NmZiLTQxNDMtOWQzMi0zYWI5Y2M2ZWE4MGIiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdGFjcy5jb20vIiwiYXVkIjoidXJuOnRlc3QiLCJleHAiOjE3MTA4MDczODl9.lJXm5hmkp5ArRIAHqVJGefW2bcTzd91iZphoKDwa6w8

Comment: pleas email ampinfo@microsoft.com so I can get more details on your scenario and help figure out what the issue is.

Comment: sraje that url is working fine, but not mine :( i have sent you the Url please have a look before this expires.

Comment: is your Media Services account inactive?

Comment: No, account is active. I tried even playing video directly from Azure Media Service, but even there I am getting same error. Is this browser issue or there is some settings I am missing. The same url works fine in some browser and not in some.

Comment: @sraje I found the issue, looks like it was not having Dash protocol when I was creating delivery policy. Thanks for your support and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my question, but finally I figured it out the issue. Here I did to fix this Issue.

1. First I checked and made sure that Streaming Endpoint is running.
   [image]
2. I was Using HLS And Smoothing protocol, seems these requires the flash support in the browser. You can a piece of code in your method where you are creating delivery policy "CreateAssetDeliveryPolicy".
   [image]
3. The above changes now will be enough to get URL to play on any browser, but if you are writing your own code for playing those encoded videos then please make sure about format. It's really not necessary but I had to enforced the encoding format to Dash.
   [image]
4. if you still face an issue in playing video, then make sure that manifest protocol(http/https) is same as the protocol(http/https) with which you are requesting.